# Socket services sending data to device to change the status of a register

Tags: vb.net

I have a the code below sending data to a PLC and i am trying to keep the status of a bit high. At the moment the bit turns on and then off after a sec. would anybody be able to help, please? Thanks

```
Private Sub ConfirmFail_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        'txtPassword.Focus()
        frmMain.Enabled = False  ' Disables the Main form so nothing runs in the background
        While frmMain.Enabled = False

            AsWritePass.set_DataWord(0, &HFF)   'write all bits (bits 11111111 00000000)
            AsWritePass.set_DataWord(1, &H80)    'bit 0 on      (H80 = 1000 0000)

            AsWritePass.NodeAddress = "192.168.10.16,,,EIP:"
            AsWritePass.Function = ASABTCPLib.enumFunction.FUNC_AB_SLC500_WRITE_BIT
            AsWritePass.MemStart = "B3:5/0"
            AsWritePass.MemQty = 8
            AsWritePass.AsyncRefresh()


        End While

        txtPassword.Focus()  
        Me.TopMost = True   


    End Sub
```